# Graphics text won't update until other operations are done

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton which performs an action when clicked. In the actionPerformed I want to update the button text before calling the NotifyObserver, which contains a big number of calculations. The problem is that the buttontext won't update until all the operations called by the NotifyObserver are done. Here's the JButton action code:

```
//Action for sinoButton
sinoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sinoButton.setText("Loading Sinogram"); //Set text while loading sinogram
        NotifyObserversSinogram(); //Notify observer and start sinogram calculation
    }
});
```

As you can see, the button text should be updated before the observers are notified. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You would run expensive computations on another thread, so you can ask UI thread to update UI whenever you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  `NotifyObserversSinogram()` does not do Swing specific computations, just drop it in another thread:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    sinoButton.setText("Loading Sinogram");
    new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            NotifyObserversSinogram();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

If it does, see [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
Since Swing is not thread safe you have to use Swingutilities:

```
JButton b = new JButton("Run query");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Thread queryThread = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        runQueries();
      }
    };
    queryThread.start();
  }
});
```

---

```
// Called from non-UI thread
private void runQueries() {
  for (int i = 0; i < noQueries; i++) {
    runDatabaseQuery(i);
    updateProgress(i);
  }
}

private void updateProgress(final int queryNo) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // Here, we can safely update the GUI
      // because we'll be called from the
      // event dispatch thread
      statusLabel.setText("Query: " + queryNo);
    }
  });
}
```

Here some more complete info about how it works: [Threading with swing](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Didn't know about that! But there's a workaround. Check the edit.

Comment: Yep, that's one, personally I prefer a `SwingWorker`, but that's me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Swing is a single threaded framework, the `ActionListener` is execute within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this will prevent the UI from been updated until the `actionPerformed` method exist

Now, you could use another thread to run your calculations in, but Swing is also not Thread safe.

A simple solution would be to use a `SwingWorker`, which has means by which you can update the UI safely, provide progress updates and also be notified when the worker is `done`

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton sinoButton = new JButton();
  //Action for sinoButton
    sinoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("Loading Sinogram"); //Set text while loading sinogram

           /*Since this is time consuming operation running on EDT its causing the issue.
            * To fix it run the time consuming operation in a thread other than EDT
            * */
            new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    NotifyObserversSinogram();
                };
            }.start();
        }
    });
```